# qt with xml and qnetworkaccessmanager

Tags: c++, xml, qnetworkaccessmanager

Im trying to make a Qt Project, where i have a `vector<todo_list>` filled with simple entrys (Name,Description,Date) only `QString` an `QDate`.
I want to save these entrys as a xml file and upload it to a server. 
Moreover i want to reload the xml from the server in my vector.

Uploading with `QNetworkAccessManager` would be the option i guess, but i only know how to upload txt files.

Maybe someone can help me with this one.